# C# List Item counting in the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am trying to make a cash register.

How it works:

Scan barcode > get price > set amount of items > get total.
Now I have ran into a problem.
As I have tried to find how to get a count going/only get a single list item(in this case a int) but that information is quite rare. As I mainly would be able to find the amount of list in gridview.

what i want: is a way to calculate the total KassaItem.Quantitiy index in my list

My code:

```
public class KassaItem // making a class for making items in list
{
 public string EanNr { get; set; }
 public string zoekName { get; set; }
 public int Quantity { get; set; } // < i want to count this but, to total it. Not the total list in gridview.
 public double Price { get; set; }       

 public KassaItem(string eanNr,string zoekname, int quantity, double price)
 {
  EanNr = eanNr;
  zoekName = zoekname;
  Quantity = quantity;
  Price = price;
 }
}

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<KassaItem> KassaNew = new List<KassaItem>();
  bool isNew = true;

  if (TextBox1.Text != "")
  {
   foreach (var KassaItem in KassaList)
   {
    if (TextBox1.Text == KassaItem.EanNr)
    {
    KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem(KassaItem.EanNr, KassaItem.zoekName, KassaItem.Quantity + 1, KassaItem.Price));
    isNew = false;
    }
    else
    {
    KassaNew.Add(KassaItem);
    }
   }

   if (isNew)
   {
   KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem(TextBox1.Text, "vochtige doekies", 1, 4.99));
   }

   KassaList = KassaNew;

   GridView1.DataSource = KassaList;
   GridView1.DataBind();

   }
   IsTrue = true;
   Counter();
   TotalAmount = TotalQuan.ToString();
   TotalItems.Text = "Quantity " + TotalAmount;
   TextBox1.Text = "";
   TextBox1.Focus();
       
   }
```

Thanks in advance and in advance have a amazing holidays for everyone,

Explodeonyou

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your question or goal is but for if you want the count for an item in your whole kassaNew-list this is the following you can use:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uGg1DU)

or here directly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// What you need:
using System.Linq;

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<KassaItem> KassaNew = new List<KassaItem>();
                KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem("yes", "Beer", 2, 20));
                KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem("yes", "Drink Cola", 1, 3.5));
                KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem("yes", "Drink Fanta", 1, 3.5));
                KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem("yes", "Chocolate Bar", 5, 10));
                KassaNew.Add(new KassaItem("yes", "Flower", 4, 40));
        
        // get single quantity
        // i have a query that searches the kassanew list after a name, you can use eanNr or anything else
        int singleItemQuantity = KassaNew.First(x => x.zoekName == "Beer").Quantity;
        int totalQuantity = 0;
        
        // get totalquantity
        foreach(KassaItem kassaItem in KassaNew)
        {
            totalQuantity += kassaItem.Quantity;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(singleItemQuantity);
        Console.WriteLine(totalQuantity);
    }
}

public class KassaItem // making a class for making items in list
{
 public string EanNr { get; set; }
 public string zoekName { get; set; }
 public int Quantity { get; set; } // < i want to count this but, to total it. Not the total list in gridview.
 public double Price { get; set; }       

 public KassaItem(string eanNr,string zoekname, int quantity, double price)
 {
  EanNr = eanNr;
  zoekName = zoekname;
  Quantity = quantity;
  Price = price;
 }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the Int in my KassaItem.Quantity(as i defended it as a Int) in Gridview to  eitherway to do a TotalQuan++; or get the KassaItem.Quantity straight value